# Pandas convertir non-null objects

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Despues de importar utilizando `urlib`, datos de Internet, consigo crear un DataFrame `(df)` con dos columnas `(Fecha y Valor)` de los tipos:

```
Fecha    1563 non-null object, 
Valor    1563 non-null object.
```

Con la sentencia `df["Fecha"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Fecha"])` consigo pasar los valores de la columna `Fecha`, al formato `Fecha    1563 non-null datetime64[ns]`

A continuación intento cambiar el formato de la columna `valor` con la sentencia `df["Valor"] = pd.to_numeric(df["Valor"])` y obtengo el error:

> ```
> ValueError: Unable to parse string "185,130000" at position 0.
> ```

Lo vuelvo a intentar con la sentencia `df['Valor'] = df['Valor'].apply(np.float)` y me da el error:

> ```
> ValueError: Unable to parse string "185,130000" at position 0
> ```

¿Qué más podría hacer?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema aparentemente es el formato de la cadena: el valor `185,130000` no puede convertirse a ningún valor numérico por que no puede interpretar la `,` como separador decimal. Una posible solución es reemplazar este carácter por el `.`:

```
# Reemplazamos la , por .
df["Valor"] = df["Valor"].str.replace(",", ".")
# Y ahora sí deberíamos poder convertirlo a numérico
df["Valor"] = pd.to_numeric(df["Valor"])
```

Por otro lado, si estás leyendo estos datos de un archivo `csv` mediante `read_csv`, tal vez te convenga configurar en ese momento, la coma (`,`) como separador decimal, usando el parámetro `decimal=','`.

Comment: Efectivamente, ese era el problema. La importación viene directamente de un link en Internet